# Can I connect a 120V outlet to a 240v well house supply?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

My well house is 300 plus feet away from our house. The pump is 240 and when we built the house the electrician ran a 3-wire from the main panel to the well house. This is the only power source in the well house. It has been getting very cold and I would like to add some sort of heat lamp or heat tape to keep it from freezing. Looking on line it seems adding a sub-panel would not work with 3-wire. Would it be safe to add a 240 range outlet and buy a cord designed to reduce 240 to 120? Seems to be used a bunch when someone goes from an electric range to a gas range. Any other options? Any help is appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Adapters are never a good idea.

Comment: Has it ever frozen before? Can you provide a few pictures?

Comment: Would be better to find a 220v heat lamp or heat strip.  They exist, but I'm not sure there is such a thing as a "cord that reduces 220 to 110".

Comment: Hey Jack. It has not. We are in our 2nd winter and its been in the 20's at night and has got me a little concerned. Built the house less than 2 years ago but the well has been there for 10 plus years. When we bought the property it was a horse farm. There was a meter on the well house. We had it removed and had our electrician run a line from the main panel on the house to the well house. I could always have the power company put the power back on but was just trying to save the base monthly fee of $30. I cannot figure out how to add a picture.

Comment: Thanks JPi1618. I think that may be my only route.

Comment: Just to be clear, you cannot legally use a 3 wire range/dryer receptacle for anything but an existing range/dryer circuit.

Comment: Btripp72, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works. "Thank you" comments are discouraged in favor of post resolution. Follow the instructions in the editor to add images.

Comment: running 2 basic, non-active 110v heat strips in series would share the voltage between them.

Comment: More than that @NoSparksPlease, you can't legally use a 3-wire range/dryer recep **except to replace a 3-wire recep**. If the house has been upgraded to 4-wire, you cannot roll it back to 3 merely because your range/dryer has a 3-wire cord.  You must change the cord, which is easy, but some people balk at that for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of a tap rule and that would not be safe in this case because you only have 3 wire no neutral. There are 220v heaters but I would suggest good insulation on the pipes and letting a faucet trickle so the pump kicks on every 5 minutes or so, I have done this in several homes and not had frozen pipes even in the low single digits and -f  but I did loose some plumbing in the barn that now has heat tape luckily we had water in the house and could shut the feed to the barn off until we got the pipes fixed.

Answer (score 0):

240V heaters are really not a problem.  You just don't find them in a shrinkwrapped box on an aisle at Walmart, and you wouldn't want a plug-in heater anyway, since they are very flimsy and don't hold up.

So I definitely would not violate at least 3 electrical codes to try to create a 120V socket there; I'd fit a 240V device.

Lighting is readily available in 240V; just look at any modern fluorescent or LED and look for "100-277 volts" or "90-306V" (that +/- 10%). That really is a range.

For heaters, just look at the kinds you permanently install; a 500W Cadet heater is first to mind, and it's only $35.  That's barely more than a cheap heater-fan. That unit will last 20 years.

For heat tape, you just have to go to industrial supply for that, and it may not be in neatly prepackaged bundles like you're used to.